# Making Animation in React for Component When Comes to Page

Tags: reactjs, animation

Guys I made an inventory app, you write name description ex. and pressing a button and boom item component comes out.

This component comes immediately, but i want to comes with an animation.

What i need to do or learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can animate using several ways.

1. The most basic way(and tiring) is to use some css and js to animate the entrance of your component.
2. You can use different animation libraries like react-spring, framer-motion etc.
3. If you want really simple animations just use https://animate.style/ you can animate your component by simply adding predefined classess. Really super EZ